# удаления объектов из файлов старше 3-х дней

Tags: java

есть файл  C:\file.txt,
 с данными

1553609880 499032348 37.202.227.207

1553609881 200058210 231.226.99.123

1553609882 484252323 191.57.97.200

....

нужно написать метод,который принимает время в миллисекундах и сравнивает его с первым параметром из этой таблицы(первый параметр тоже время в миллисекундах), и если файл был создан более 3-х дней назад, удалить эти данные из файла(т е перезаписать файл заново уже без строки 1553609881 200058210 231.226.99.123 )

моя идея была - считать все первые данные(первые цифры) - закинуть их в лист и сравнить,если более  3-х дней,то не перезаписывать, если нет, то снова записать.

этот метод возвращяет все первые числа, а вт как сравнить и снова записать не пойму

```
public static List<String> returnArray() {
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("C:\\file.txt"));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.trim().split("\\s+");
                if (parts.length > 0 && !parts[0].isEmpty()) {
                    items.add(parts[0]);
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return items;
    }
```

что тут не верно?

```
public class Main {
    private final static long THREE_DAYS_AGO = 259200L;
    public static void deleteMethod(Long timeNew) {

        try {
            RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\Users\\djoni\\Desktop\\Java\\InputStream\\log\\file.txt","rwd");
            long threeDaysAgo = LocalDateTime.now().minusDays(3).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC).toEpochMilli() / 1000;
            String line;
            while ((line = raf.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] parts = line.trim().split("\\s+");
                if (Long.parseLong(parts[0]) <= THREE_DAYS_AGO + timeNew) {
                    raf.writeBytes(line);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

        public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        deleteMethod(  1553177880L);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы можете открыть файл, прочитать строку и сразу ее удалить, если она вам не подходит.

Comment: каким образом? вроде прямого удаление нет или?

Comment: Первый параметр у вас - время в секундах, а не миллисекундах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Parser {

    private final static long THREE_DAYS_AGO = 259200L;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        String fileName = "file.txt";

        reader(fileName, 1553177880L);

    }

    public static void reader (final String fileName, final long timeDate) throws IOException{

        try (final Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName))) {
            Files.write(Paths.get(fileName), stream
                    .filter(s -> Long.valueOf(s.split(" ")[0].trim()) <= timeDate+THREE_DAYS_AGO)
                    .collect(Collectors.joining("\r")).getBytes());

        }

    }

}
```

Я не пойму, как соотносится время создания файла и параметр, передаваемый в метод. Что с чем сравнивать? Сейчас удаляются все строки, с указанным временем (первый параметр), который меньшим чем 3 дня от текущей даты. Но в этом случае метод никаких дат не принимает... Посему комментируйте, если что-то не подходит.

Comment: передаваемый пераметр - это время в миллисекундах, т е если первый параметр в таблице(это время создания файла в миллесекундах)  больше чем дата,которую мы передаем в параметре на три дня, то удаляем эту строку из файла

Comment: ошибка выскакивает Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""

Comment: если у вас ошибка, то это значит, что на вход прилетает не число. дайте свой тхт файл. идею понял, заодно и параметр в аргументы добавлю

Comment: логику подправил касаемо передаваемого параметра. если выложите тхт в полном объеме, то помогу отдебажить

Comment: я нашел в чем ошибка была, у меня первая строка была пустая,осталось подправить,чтобы входящий параметр в методе был временем (в миллисекундах),от которого надо отнять три дня

Comment: спасибо,все работает

Comment: только один маленький вопрос, почему (s.split(" ")[0].trim()) всегда нулевой элемент? правильно я понимаю, что мы переходим на следующую строку, и поэтому он там снова нулевой?

Comment: что вы понимаете под нулевым?Files.lines вычитывает ваш файл построчно (эта функция из коробки) и пробрасывает прочитанное в стрим. Теперь строка по сути это одна переменная типа стринг (хотя в контексте стрима говорить про одну переменную не совсем корректно).функция фильтр получает именно эту переменную типа стринг с одной строкой из потока, этот объект находится в переменной s, у этой переменной вызывается сплит, из полученного массива слов берется элемент номер ноль, парсится в лонг и сравнивается с датой. так осуществляется фильтрование. итого в переменную s по очереди попадают все строки

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать 
`RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile("C:\\file.txt","rwd");`
Дальше используете вашу логику. Вот [ссылка](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/RandomAccessFile.html) на документацию.

**UPD**

```
void modifyFile(long time) {
    long THREE_DAYS_AGO = 3 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000L;
    try {
     File file = new File("text.txt");
                RandomAccessFile raf = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rwd");
                String line;
                long pointer = 0;
                while ((line = raf.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.startsWith(Long.toString(time)) && (file.lastModified() > THREE_DAYS_AGO )) {
                        raf.seek(pointer);
                        for (long i = pointer; i < line.length(); i++) {
                            raf.writeBytes(" ");
                        }
                        line.replaceAll("\\s", "");
                    }
                    pointer += line.length();
                }
                raf.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }
```

Comment: спасибо,интересный способ

Comment: попробовал написать по вашему варианту, скажите,что не так?

Comment: @Djoni, Так у вас же есть уже ответ, который вас устроил. К тому же, где код? как я пойму, что не так?

Comment: извини, комп тупит,сейчас напишу. Да тот ответ подходит,но твой вариант интересный,хотел бы разобраться на будущее, добавил в описание

Comment: Вопрос прям как на собеседовании, "Что тут не верно?". Что не верно, то? Ошибка, или файл не изменяется.

Comment: извините,не правильно сформулировал - файл не изменяется

Comment: Как минимум, вы в line сохраняете эту же самую строку, которую прочли. Потом, вы не закрываете RandomAccessFile после его чтения. Это то, что видно на 1 взгляд

Comment: ну,по логике,если нулевой элемент подходит,то его записываем,если нет,то пропускаем